# How to trigger a function only when an option is selected in multiple <select> tags in html?

Tags: html

I have three `<select>` tags in my html code

I want to trigger a function only when all the three `<select>` tags have an option selected (except for the `default` one). How do I do that?

```html
<p id="cln_name"><b>Colony name</b> :&nbsp;
  <select name="colony_name" id="colony_name" style="max-width:90%;">
    <option value="default" selected="selected_code">Select your colony name</option>
    <option value="code_one" selected="selected_code">PCR235LK</option>
    <option value="code_two" selected="selected_code">AHF21IOD</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p id="cln_type"><b>Type</b> :&nbsp;
  <select name="colony_type" id="colony_type">
    <option value="default" selected="selected_type">Select your colony type</option>
    <option value="ONE" selected="selected_type">I</option>
    <option value="TWO" selected="selected_type">II</option>
    <option value="THREE" selected="selected_type">III</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p id="qrtr_no"><b>Quarter No</b> :&nbsp;
  <select name="quarter_no" id="quarter_no">
    <option value="default" selected="selected_type">Select your quarter no</option>
    <option value="first" selected="selected_type">ABC/12</option>
    <option value="second" selected="selected_type">DEF/34</option>
  </select>
</p>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a jquery code with little bit update in your html code, instead of every option called as selected I just mentioned only default one as selected, rest is you can check your code, hope it will help if I understood your requirement correctly.

```js
$("#colony_name,#colony_type,#quarter_no").on("change", function() {
  var colony_name = $("#colony_name").val();
  var colony_type = $("#colony_type").val();

  var quarter_no = $("#quarter_no").val();
  if (colony_name != "default" && colony_type != "default" && quarter_no != "default") {
    alert("call your function in this function tag"); //call your function or execution here
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="cln_name"><b>Colony name</b> :&nbsp;
  <select name="colony_name" id="colony_name" style="max-width:90%;">
    <option value="default" selected="selected_code">Select your colony name</option>
    <option value="code_one">PCR235LK</option>
    <option value="code_two">AHF21IOD</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p id="cln_type"><b>Type</b> :&nbsp;
  <select name="colony_type" id="colony_type">
    <option value="default" selected="selected_type">Select your colony type</option>
    <option value="ONE">I</option>
    <option value="TWO">II</option>
    <option value="THREE">III</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p id="qrtr_no"><b>Quarter No</b> :&nbsp;
  <select name="quarter_no" id="quarter_no">
    <option value="default" selected="selected_type">Select your quarter no</option>
    <option value="first">ABC/12</option>
    <option value="second">DEF/34</option>
  </select>
</p>
```

Comment: Where is the question tagged jQuery?

Comment: jQuery is helper library to sort out things easily. I have given the solution as per requirements. If someone asks question for JavaScript we can use jQuery, its not prohibited at all

Comment: OP did not even ask for JavaScript but it is needed. jQuery is a complication and an additional burden on OP to learn a framework when Vanilla JS is sufficient

Answer (score 0):

Delegate and use every

Vanilla JavaScript

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const selects = [...container.querySelectorAll('select')];
container.addEventListener('change',function() {
  const noDefault = selects.every(sel => sel.value !='default');
  console.log(noDefault);
  if (noDefault) alert("Yes"); // execute if noDefault is true
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
<p id="cln_name"><b>Colony name</b> :&nbsp;
  <select name="colony_name" id="colony_name" style="max-width:90%;">
    <option value="default" selected="selected_code">Select your colony name</option>
    <option value="code_one" selected="selected_code">PCR235LK</option>
    <option value="code_two" selected="selected_code">AHF21IOD</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p id="cln_type"><b>Type</b> :&nbsp;
  <select name="colony_type" id="colony_type">
    <option value="default" selected="selected_type">Select your colony type</option>
    <option value="ONE" selected="selected_type">I</option>
    <option value="TWO" selected="selected_type">II</option>
    <option value="THREE" selected="selected_type">III</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p id="qrtr_no"><b>Quarter No</b> :&nbsp;
  <select name="quarter_no" id="quarter_no">
    <option value="default" selected="selected_type">Select your quarter no</option>
    <option value="first" selected="selected_type">ABC/12</option>
    <option value="second" selected="selected_type">DEF/34</option>
  </select>
</p></div>
```

jQuery

```js
$('#container select').on('change', function() {
  const vals = $(this)
    .closest('#container')
    .find('select')
    .map(function() {
      return this.value
    })
    .get(); // values of selects in container
  console.log(vals)
  const noDefault = vals.every(val => val != 'default');
  // console.log(noDefault);
  if (noDefault) console.log("Yes"); // execute if noDefault is true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <p id="cln_name"><b>Colony name</b> :&nbsp;
    <select name="colony_name" id="colony_name" style="max-width:90%;">
      <option value="default" selected="selected_code">Select your colony name</option>
      <option value="code_one" selected="selected_code">PCR235LK</option>
      <option value="code_two" selected="selected_code">AHF21IOD</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p id="cln_type"><b>Type</b> :&nbsp;
    <select name="colony_type" id="colony_type">
      <option value="default" selected="selected_type">Select your colony type</option>
      <option value="ONE" selected="selected_type">I</option>
      <option value="TWO" selected="selected_type">II</option>
      <option value="THREE" selected="selected_type">III</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p id="qrtr_no"><b>Quarter No</b> :&nbsp;
    <select name="quarter_no" id="quarter_no">
      <option value="default" selected="selected_type">Select your quarter no</option>
      <option value="first" selected="selected_type">ABC/12</option>
      <option value="second" selected="selected_type">DEF/34</option>
    </select>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Its triggering even when I select an option in a single dropdown. I want to `console.log("changed")`, when all three of the dropdowns have changed, not when either one of them changed

Comment: @Lubji So what did you not understand in my code? If you wanted a jQuery version you could have tagged your question jQuery

Comment: I made you a jQuery version too